# OkHttp throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, okhttp

I'm getting a lot of crashes in production and cannot figure out what could be a reason. I haven't been able to find any particular steps to reproduce it. It happened only once on one of my devices.

We're using multiple instances of OkHttp for different cases.

- Instance for regular REST API calls and also passed to Coil (image loading library) instance. It has 4 custom interceptors. 3 interceptors are used just to add some custom headers to request. And 4th interceptor to logout user if response code is 401
- Instance is used to connect web sockets. Doesn't have any custom interceptors
- 2 more instances without interceptors for making requests to some public APIs
- Also an instance or few is probably used by SendBird library

As you can see from info below the most popular variant of crash doesn't include any custom interceptors in stacktrace, and the least popular does include.
The second variant looks more like a web sockets related.

Variant of crashes:

**Variant 1** - 28 events

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException:
   at okio.OutputStreamSink.write(OutputStreamSink.java:55)
   at okio.AsyncTimeout$sink$1.write(AsyncTimeout.kt:102)
   at okio.RealBufferedSink.flush(RealBufferedSink.kt:267)
   at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.finishRequest(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:155)
   at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.finishRequest(Exchange.java:95)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:79)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
   at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
   at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
   at io.sentry.android.okhttp.SentryOkHttpInterceptor.intercept(SentryOkHttpInterceptor.kt:101)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
   at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.kt:154)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
   at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
   at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

**Variant 2** - 12 events

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException:
   at okio.OutputStreamSink.write(OutputStreamSink.java:55)
   at okio.AsyncTimeout$sink$1.write(AsyncTimeout.kt:102)
   at okio.RealBufferedSink.emit(RealBufferedSink.kt:261)
   at okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketWriter.writeMessageFrame(WebSocketWriter.kt:195)
   at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.writeOneFrame$okhttp(RealWebSocket.kt:527)
   at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket$WriterTask.runOnce(RealWebSocket.kt:620)
   at okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner.runTask(TaskRunner.kt:116)
   at okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner.access$runTask(TaskRunner.kt:42)
   at okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner$runnable$1.run(TaskRunner.kt:65)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

**Variant 3** - 6 events

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException:
   at okio.OutputStreamSink.write(OutputStreamSink.java:55)
   at okio.AsyncTimeout$sink$1.write(AsyncTimeout.kt:102)
   at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.kt:255)
   at okio.RealBufferedSink.writeUtf8(RealBufferedSink.kt:162)
   at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.writeRequest(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:164)
   at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.writeRequestHeaders(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:119)
   at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.writeRequestHeaders(Exchange.java:63)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:41)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
   {...my custom interceptors here...}
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
   at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
   at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
   at io.sentry.android.okhttp.SentryOkHttpInterceptor.intercept(SentryOkHttpInterceptor.kt:101)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
   at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
   at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Please give some advices how I can improve crash reports, populate it with some useful info that can help figuring out what is a problem here.

Comment: I think a little sample code would help